# Azure Cognitive Search - MergeOrUpdate to a only retrievable field

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

What happens when "updating" a document, but only changing a retrievable field. Will the document be reindexed?
I'm trying to mesure the "cost" of updating a retrievable field to a lot of documents to decide if I should put this field on the index or getting from SQL Server after consulting the index.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`MergeOrUpdate` behavior is the same as `Merge`, if the document (document key specifically) already exists. It doesn't matter which are the properties of the field (retrievable, filterable, etc.). In other words, the whole document is not re-indexed, but the specified field values in the call are merged. For more information on the REST API behavior: [Add, Update or Delete Documents (Azure Cognitive Search REST API)](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents).